# Using sed to substitute text and add text after certain pattern

Tags: linux, sed, command-line

I'm looking to substitute text inside a file after a certain pattern.

###### For example:

The content of `example.txt` is

```bsh
Something==x.y.z
```

I'd like to change it to

```bsh
Something>=x.y.z,<x.y.z+1.0
```

I know I can use `sed -i 's/==/>=/g' example.txt` to change the `==` but I do not know add `<x.y.z+1.0` after a certain pattern.

(*Please note that `x.y.z` is a random number*)

**EDIT:** it is for Python packages. Examples

```
argcomplete==1.12.3
youtube-dl==2021.6.6
systemd-python==234
```

would become

```
argcomplete>=1.12.3,<1.12.3+1.0
youtube-dl>=2021.6.6,<2021.6.6+1.0
systemd-python>=234,<234+1.0
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following `sed` command assumes that there is exactly one `==` in the line and extracts the parts before and after it as groups 1 and 2 which can be used in the substitution.

```
sed 's/\(.*\)==\(.*\)/\1>=\2,<\2+1.0/'
```

With the input

```
Something==x.y.z
argcomplete==1.12.3
youtube-dl==2021.6.6
systemd-python==234
```

the output is

```
Something>=x.y.z,<x.y.z+1.0
argcomplete>=1.12.3,<1.12.3+1.0
youtube-dl>=2021.6.6,<2021.6.6+1.0
systemd-python>=234,<234+1.0
```

To edit the file in-place, add option `-i` and the name of the input file:

```
sed -i 's/\(.*\)==\(.*\)/\1>=\2,<\2+1.0/' example.txt
```

**Explanation:**

Pattern:

- `.` = any character
- `*` = the preceding pattern repeated from 0 to any number
- --> `.*` = any number of any characters
- `\(`...`\)` = capture the text matching the enclosed pattern
- `==` = literal text
- `\(.*\)==\(.*\)` = any text captured as group 1 followed by `==` and any text captured as group 2

Replacement:

- `\1`, `\2` = text from capture group 1 or 2
- other parts are literal text here
- `\1>=\2,<\2+1.0` = *group 1* `>=` *group2* `,<` *group2* `+1.0`

---

As mentioned in [they](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/493832/they)'s comment, the first pattern before the literal `==` can be omitted, resulting in

```
sed 's/==\(.*\)/>=\1,<\1+1.0/'
```

The explanation is similar with the difference that `sed` will only modify the matching part of the line. So the part before `==` will be preserved, and only one capture group for the part after the `==` is necessary.

A difference in the behavior of the two patterns is that `.*==`... will match the last `==` while `==`... will match the first one because the `.*` part matches the longest possible text that is followed by `==`.

Comment: Somewhat shorter: `sed 's/==\(.*\)/>=\1,<\1+1.0/'`, unless you explicitly want to match the _last_ `==` on the line.